# Metric Space with every subset open

Tags: metric-spaces

$(X,d)$ metric space. If $c>0$ so that $d(x,y)>c$ , $x \neq y$
Show that every subset of $X$ is open. That reminds me a lot of the descrete metric space but i cant quite make the connection so i started simply.Say $A\subset X$ I am trying to find an $ε$ so i can prove that for every $x$ there is an open ball with center $x$ in $A$ but i cant quite get it. Could someone lend me a hand or any hint on this one? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Show that the singleton sets $\{x\}$ are open. If $\{x\}$ contains an open ball and $\{x\} \subseteq A$, then...

Comment: @TheoBendit So say my ball has radius $ε<c$. If $ε>0$ then the only point it contains is the point it's centred on. So any single point has a ball of some radius around it containing only that point.So we know that every singleton is open.Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. Now, finish the argument. :-)

Comment: What you need is $x \neq y \implies d(x,y) \gt c$.  It is not clear from the way you wrote the question that this is what you are given.  Replacing the comma with if would do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Take any subset $A \subset E$, and $x \in A$. Show that
$$B \left(x, \frac{c}{2} \right) = \lbrace x \rbrace \subset A$$

where $B(a,r)$ denotes the ball centered at $a$ and radius $r$. Then conclude that you have a ball included in $A$ around every point of $A$, so $A$ is open.